# I want to use excel to get data from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, excel, vba

I have been use excel query ,how come I cant GET the data from

http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wpq.aspx?date=21-11-2015&venue=st&lang=en

what can I do?

I had been struggle a few days, can you help me write a code for excel `vba`.
I have already tried to search a lot, like yahoo google

That's the table I want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Excel version you can download the free Power Query add-in from Microsoft (Excel 2010 and 2013) or use the new Get & Transform in Excel 2016.

These queries do recognize the tables on the page as Table 5 and Table 6. The query in M code is

for Table 5

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wpq.aspx?date=21-11-2015&venue=st&lang=en")),
    Data5 = Source{5}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data5,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", Int64.Type}, {"Column5", Int64.Type}, {"Column6", Int64.Type}, {"Column7", Int64.Type}, {"Column8", Int64.Type}, {"Column9", Int64.Type}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}, {"Column12", type text}, {"Column13", type text}, {"Column14", type text}, {"Column15", type text}, {"Column16", type text}, {"Column17", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type")
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

similar for table 6. Load them into the workbook and take it from there. You can refresh the query at any time.

Comment: THANK YOUR HELP TRYLYN
HOW ABOUT EXCEL2007?
CAN YOU TELL THE STEP?
i only need to copy those coed IN TO EXCEL VISUAL BASIC??

Comment: As I wrote in my post, the Power Query add-in is available for 2010 and 2013 and built into 2016. No other versions. And that code cannot be used in VBA. It's a completely new way of accessing data.

Comment: Have you taken the [Stackoverflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)? That will help you.